# Xtensa xt-xcc license issue

Tags: xtensa

I am trying to use Xtensa cross compiler to build a simple embedded application.

And I got 2 mysterious issues.

**The first issue is probably a license issue:**

The Xtensa toolchain always reports below error:

```
License checkout failed: No such feature exists.
Feature:       XTENSA_XCC_TIE
License path:  84300@xtensa03p.xxx.xxx.com:/root/xtensa/XtDevTools/install/tools/RG-2019.12-linux/XtensaTools/Tools/lic/license.dat:
FLEXnet Licensing error:-5,147
For further information, refer to the FLEXnet Licensing documentation,
available at "www.macrovision.com".
```

This looks like a license issue.
According to [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Common-FlexNet-error-codes.html), the `-5` error code means `No such feature exists`. But I didn't find what `147` means. And I am not sure about how FLEXnet works. It seems to be a popular licensing mechanism.

But I can ping through the `xtensa03p.xxx.xxx.com` server. So I think the license server is alive.

**The second issue:**

When I try to check the cross compiler `xt-xcc` version:

```
/root/xtensa/XtDevTools/install/tools/RG-2019.12-linux/XtensaTools/bin/xt-xcc --version
```

I got below warning:

```
Warning: The location of this program does not match the Xtensa Tools
location specified in the Xtensa registry entry:

  program prefix: /root/xtensa/XtDevTools/install/tools/RG-2019.12-linux/XtensaTools/bin/..
  registry value: /root/xtensa/XtDevTools/install/tools/RI-2021.7-linux/XtensaTools

Either the current Xtensa configuration is not properly installed or you
are using Xtensa Tools from a different location than you specified when
installing the configuration.

xt-xcc version 12.0.12
Thread model: single
```

I don't know where the `Xtensa registry entry` is. Should I modify it to match my `xt-xcc` installation path?

Could anyone shed some light?